# "Could not find symbol"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, embed

I'm trying to embed an swf file in this way:

```
[Embed(source="../assets/assets.swf", symbol="main")]
public var MC:Class;
```

However, it keeps saying that error, "Could not find symbol main in...".

I've checked that the linkage of the symbol is indeed main.

What else should I check?.

Thanks.

(the file is found, if I remove the embed I can add the entire swf to the stage without problems)

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your syntax. The only place that you could be making a mistake is the name of the symbol. Use the ApplicationDomain.getDefinition() and ApplicationDomain.getQualifiedDefinitionNames() APIs to verify that the symbol name is correct.

The other problem might be that the file that contains the symbol is in a different location from the one being embedded. It sounds dumb, but I've done worse things when working on a tight deadline.

Answer (score 0):

Example1: 
if structure folder is 
src(folder)
  --core
      -- Assets.as
assets(folder)
  -fly01.png
The error because the directory path not extracly ( asset folder outside core folder)
Asset.as you write error:
package core 
{
    import starling.textures.Texture;

```
public class Assets
{
    [Embed(source="assets/sky.png")]
    private static var sky:Class;
    public static var skyTexture:Texture;
}
```

}
Asset.as you write:error
package core 
{
    import starling.textures.Texture;

```
public class Assets
{
    [Embed(source="../assets/sky.png")]
    private static var sky:Class;
    public static var skyTexture:Texture;
}
```

}
Asset.as you write:true
package core 
{
    import starling.textures.Texture;

```
public class Assets
{
    [Embed(source="../../assets/sky.png")]
    private static var sky:Class;
    public static var skyTexture:Texture;
}
```

}